# Ignore spaces when auto formatting automatic properties

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, formatting

When I declare some automatic properties in a class, I like to align them as following for the sake of readability:

```
public Boolean SomeShortProperty                      { get; set; }
public Boolean SomeOtherShortProperty                 { get; set; }
public Boolean SomeLooooooooooooooooooooooongProperty { get; set; }
```

When I use "Format document" <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>, Visual Studio removes the extra spaces:

```
public Boolean SomeShortProperty { get; set; }
public Boolean SomeOtherShortProperty { get; set; }
public Boolean SomeLooooooooooooooooooooooongProperty { get; set; }
```

I've checked the "Ignore spaces in declaration statements" option, but it doesn't change anything.

[image: screenshot]

Any solution to prevent VS to remove those spaces?

Comment: Are those really spaces or tabs?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Spaces

Answer (score 0):

The option you have enabled in the image only applies to statements; it does not apply to method signatures or properties.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to prevent the formatting of method signatures or properties without a custom extension.

Also, this is still the same behavior in VS2013 and there are no additional options.